# In app.config does supportedRuntime sku define only the EARLIEST framework allowed

Tags: app-config, .net-framework-version

In app.config it is possible to define one (or more than one) `supportedRuntime`, for example:

```
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1"/> 
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/> 
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
```

Does the `sku` setting define only the *earliest* version allowed, while allowing for later versions?

I am trying to understand [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/startup/supportedruntime-element#:%7E:text=NET%20Framework%204%20and%20later,configuration%20file%20and%20the%20installed%20.):

> If ... the installed .NET Framework version is lower then [sic] the
> specified supported version, the application fails to run and instead
> displays a message asking to install the supported version. Otherwise,
> the application attempts to run on *any* installed version, but it may
> behave unexpectedly if it is not fully compatible with that version.

[my emphasis]

What does it mean, "the application attempts to run on *any* installed version"?

In the choice of which of several defined frameworks to use, is preference given to the latest or to the earliest? Or does the choice follow the physical order of the supportedRuntime list?

With respect to later versions: if the app.config is as it is set forth in my example above (4.7.1, 4.6.1, and 4.6) but Framework 4.7.**1** is not installed, yet Frameworks 4.6.1 and 4.7.**2** are both installed, would the app.config setting above *prevent* 4.7.**2** from being used?